# C++: My linked list tail doesn't change? I can't seem to get the nodes to point to each other correctly?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list with nodes and traverse through the nodes. However, my linked list tail stays the same and doesn't update.

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "stockclass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    LinkedList myList;

    ifstream file("stocks.txt");


    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) 
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string symbol;
        string numstr;

        getline(ss, symbol, ',');

        getline(ss, numstr, ',');
        stringstream priceSS(numstr);
        double price = 0;
        priceSS >> price;

        getline(ss, numstr, ',');
        stringstream sharesSS(numstr);
        int numOfShares = 0;
        sharesSS >> numOfShares;

        stock myStock(symbol, price, numOfShares);

        Node newNode(myStock);

        myList.add_node(newNode);

        cout << myList.head << ", " << myList.tail << endl;
        cout << myStock.symbol << ", " << myStock.price << ", " << myStock.numOfStocks << endl;

    };

    MyList.print();
    return 0;

}
```

stocks.txt file

```
GOOG,250.00,380
APPL,180.00,400
MEIS,46.00,67
```

.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stockclass.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;


stock::stock() {

    symbol = "";
    price = 0.00;
    numOfStocks = 0;
};

stock::stock(string sym, double pri, int num) {

    symbol = sym;
    price = pri;
    numOfStocks = num;


};

stock::printStock() {

    cout << symbol << ", " << price << ", " << numOfStocks;

}




Node::Node(stock myStock) {

    next = NULL;
    s = myStock;

};

void Node::printNode() {

    cout << s.symbol << ", " << s.price << ", " << s.numOfStocks << endl;

};


LinkedList::LinkedList() {

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

};

void LinkedList::add_node(Node& n) {

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = &n;
        tail = &n;

    } else {
        tail->next = &n;
        tail = &n;
        n.next = NULL;
    };

};

void LinkedList::print() {

    head->printNode();
    //Node *tempPointer = tail;

    if (tail != NULL) {

        tail->printNode();
        tail = tail->next;

    };
};
```

.h file

```
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class stock {

    public:

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, stock s);
        string symbol;
        double price;
        int numOfStocks;

        stock();
        stock(string sym, double pri, int num);
        printStock();


};

class Node {

    public:
        Node *next;
        stock s;
        Node();
        Node(stock myStock);
        void printNode();

};

class LinkedList {

    public:

        Node *head;
        Node *tail;

        LinkedList();
        void add_node(Node& n);
        void print();
        static void display(Node *head);

};
```

This is the output when I try to linkedlist.print();

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0OdT.jpg

The linkedlist.print() output is after Please insert number choice: 3

Not sure what I need to fix....
The tail address is the same in all 3 of the while loops. 
I don't know why it's not updating correctly.

Comment: `head = &n;` then `tail = &n;` ... are all wrong. You can't store pointers to local variables that go out of scope.

Comment: I recommend keeping files to one theme.  Make one source file for `stock` another for `node` and one for the `LinkedList`.  You can tell you build system to compile them and link them together.

Comment: @drescherjm, what does that mean? Are pointers referring to head and tail? And the local variable being n?

Comment: @drescherjm, but doesn't doing &n making it a reference call avoid that problem?

Comment: One of the common effects of storing a pointer to a local variable is the address keeps getting reused. You enter the function the first time, you get a variable at, say, address 10. The function exits and the variable at 10 is automatically freed. The next time the function enters, odds are decent that address 10 will be used again for the next node. This node also goes out of scope and is freed. The third time the program enters, guess what? 10 is used yet again.

Comment: To make this work you need to `new` and `delete` nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You should be allocating new nodes inside of the `LinkedList` class. It is not the caller's responsibility to allocate nodes for the list.

Also, the implementation of your `print()` method doesn't even try to traverse the list at all.

In short, the design of your `LinkedList` class is all wrong. Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class stock {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const stock &s);

    string symbol;
    double price;
    int numOfStocks;

    stock();
    stock(string sym, double pri, int num);

    void printStock();
};

class Node {
public:
    Node *next;
    stock s;

    Node(const stock &myStock);

    void printNode();
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();

    void add_node(const stock &s);
    void print();

    static void display(Node *head);
};
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stockclass.h"

using namespace std;

stock::stock() {
    symbol = "";
    price = 0.00;
    numOfStocks = 0;
}

stock::stock(string sym, double pri, int num) {
    symbol = sym;
    price = pri;
    numOfStocks = num;
}

void stock::printStock() {
    cout << symbol << ", " << price << ", " << numOfStocks;
}

Node::Node(const stock &myStock) {
    next = NULL;
    s = myStock;
}

void Node::printNode() {
    cout << s.symbol << ", " << s.price << ", " << s.numOfStocks << endl;
}

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    Node *n = head;
    while (n) {
        Node *next = n->next;
        delete n;
        n = next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::add_node(const stock &s) {
    Node *n = new Node(s);
    if (!head)
        head = n;
    if (tail)
        tail->next = n;
    tail = n;
}

void LinkedList::print() {
    Node *n = head;
    while (n) {
        n->printNode();
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "stockclass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    LinkedList myList;

    ifstream file("stocks.txt");

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        istringstream ss(line);
        string symbol;
        string numstr;

        getline(ss, symbol, ',');

        getline(ss, numstr, ',');
        istringstream priceSS(numstr);
        double price = 0;
        priceSS >> price;

        getline(ss, numstr, ',');
        istringstream sharesSS(numstr);
        int numOfShares = 0;
        sharesSS >> numOfShares;

        stock myStock(symbol, price, numOfShares);
        myList.add_node(myStock);

        cout << myList.head << ", " << myList.tail << endl;
        cout << myStock.symbol << ", " << myStock.price << ", " << myStock.numOfStocks << endl;
    }

    MyList.print();
    return 0;
}
```

This is, by far, not a complete implementation, but it will get you started. For instance, you need to add a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator to the `LinkedList` class, per the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). And implement your `operator<<` for `stock`. And so on.